# How do I make a post request?

Tags: c#, json, swagger, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

How do I solve the errors I get when I try to make a POST request?

I have tried executing the following json code via swagger:

```
{


"productID": 0,
  "productName": "string",
  "price": 0,
  "marketID": 0,
  "market": {
    "marketID": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "budget": 0,
    "startDate": "2019-12-10",
    "productGuideID": 0,
    "rowVersion": "string",
    "administrator": {
      "hireDate": "2019-12-10",
      "productAssignments": [
        null
      ],
      "countryAssignment": {
        "productGuideID": 0,
        "location": "string"
      },
      "id": 0,
      "lastName": "string",
      "firstMidName": "string"
    },
    "products": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "subscriptionID": 0,
      "productID": 0,
      "customerID": 0,
      "customerLoyalty": 0,
      "customer": {
        "subscriptionDate": "2019-12-10",
        "subscriptions": [
          null
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "lastName": "string",
        "firstMidName": "string"
      }
    }
  ],
  "productAssignments": [
    {
      "productGuideID": 0,
      "productID": 0,
      "productGuide": {
        "hireDate": "2019-12-10",
        "productAssignments": [
          null
        ],
        "countryAssignment": {
          "productGuideID": 0,
          "location": "string"
        },
        "id": 0,
        "lastName": "string",
        "firstMidName": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After I execute it I think I am getting a 400 response from the server:
[image: Server response 1]
I also think I am getting a 200 success response?:
[image: Server response 2]
I have also tried to put the standard json code from swagger into Postman and there I get a 404 error:
[image: Postman 404 error]

The following is my Http Post method which is in my ProductsController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        _context.Products.Add(product);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (ProductExists(product.ProductID))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetProduct", new { id = product.ProductID }, 

product);
        }
```

The following is a link to my github repository where the VitekAPI project is:
https://github.com/tux-superman/MVCandAPI

My Product model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace VitekSky.Models
{
public class Product
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "Product Number")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }


    [Range(0, 99999)]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int MarketID { get; set; }


    public Market Market { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductAssignment> ProductAssignments { get; set; }

}
}
```

My Market model:

```
 public class Market
{
    public int MarketID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Budget { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public int? ProductGuideID { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public ProductGuide Administrator { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The payload you are sending looks like an _example_ generated by swagger based on the data types it knows of. Take a look at your error, it says that it can't be converted into a byte array.

Comment: Your second image does not tell you that you executed a REST endpoint with a 200 response code, it's an _example_ of what a 200 _would be_.

Comment: @gunr2171 Okay so the error has something to do with  "errors": {
    "$.market.rowVersion": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Byte[]. Path: $.market.rowVersion | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 176." So it seems like there is a problem with me using a byte array called rowVersions. I use that for concurrency conflicts in the database. Not sure how I should solve the issue with it no being able to be converted into a byte array. Perhaps the standard JSON from swagger is not correct? Because in the JSON it says "    "rowVersion": "string",

Comment: Swagger gives you an _example_ json payload where the "rowVersion" property is set to `string`, BECAUSE THAT PROPERTY IS A STRING IN CODE. Swagger isn't smart enough to know that it's going to be later converted into a byte array. What does your modal actually look like?

Comment: @gunr2171 Aaah okay thankyou. I have added my Product model and my Market model in the post. My rowVersion property is in my Market class.

Comment: Am not sure how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you bind `"string"` to `byte[]`.`rowVersion` is an 8-byte array. Each byte represents a section of a 64-bit integer and will be 0 - 255.

You do not need to set a value for `RowVersion`,just remove it from your json if you intend to create a model.

Besides, you'd better not copy the example values of swagger as your request body without any change.It just gives you a sample format.

In you case,you need to replace `[null]` to null.

A working json could be like:

```
{
"productID": 0,
"productName": "string",
"price": 0,
"marketID": 0,
"market": {
  "marketID": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "budget": 0,
  "startDate": "2019-12-10",
  "productGuideID": 0,
  "administrator": {
    "hireDate": "2019-12-10",
    "productAssignments": null,
    "countryAssignment": {
      "productGuideID": 0,
      "location": "string"
    },
    "id": 0,
    "lastName": "string",
    "firstMidName": "string"
  },

  "products": null

},
"subscriptions": [
  {
    "subscriptionID": 0,
    "productID": 0,
    "customerID": 0,
    "customerLoyalty": 0,
    "customer": {
      "subscriptionDate": "2019-12-10",
      "subscriptions": null,

      "id": 0,
      "lastName": "string",
      "firstMidName": "string"
    }
  }
],
"productAssignments": [
  {
    "productGuideID": 0,
    "productID": 0,
    "productGuide": {
      "hireDate": "2019-12-10",
      "productAssignments": null,
      "countryAssignment": {
        "productGuideID": 0,
        "location": "string"
      },
      "id": 0,
      "lastName": "string",
      "firstMidName": "string"
    }
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code in class ProductsController.cs

i see there is no post request with "Products" and "Prod" URI those you are using in your swagger and postman

/api/Products & 
/api/Prod

This is the reason you are facing 404 error

Note: if you can provide me any url i can give it a try to test it